# MongoDB Add More users to a field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection for company users. Inside of this, the company is able to add in their team members to a field called: "teamMemberDetails"

For example, see a demo of what it currently looks like when I put a user into the DB through my API.

```
{
    "teamMemberDetails": [
        {
            "memberEmail": "example2@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "teamMembers": "0",
    "_id": "62fc49b53bcb32ca823466dc",
    "companyTitle": "Working Acc!v2",
}
```

It's also worth mentioning the schema is:

```
const CompanyProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        companyTitle:{type:String, required: true, unique: true, default: ""},
        companyPassword:{type:String, required: true, default: ""},
        centralEmail:{type:String, required: true, unique: true, default: ""},
        description:{type:String, required: true, default: ""},
        inviteToken:{type:String, required: true, default:""},
        industry:{type:String, required: true},
        employees:{type: Number},
        companyImage: {type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        locationCity:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        industry:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        country:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        teamMembers: {
            type: String, required: true, default: 0
        },
        teamMemberDetails: {
            memberName: String, default: "",
            memberEmail: String, default: "",
            memberRole: String, default: ""
        },
        highlights: {type: Array},
        isAdmin:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        isVerified:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        accountLevel: {type: Array},
        emailAuthorised: { type: Boolean, default: false},
        invitedUsers: {type: Array}
    },
);
```

This user was placed in with an API request like below:

```
//UPDATE Company - PROFILE
router.put("/updateCompany/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedUser = await CompanyProfile.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $set: req.body,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

However, i'd like this team members detail to build, for example i'd like something like this:

```
    "teamMemberDetails": [
        {
            "memberEmail": "example2@hotmail.com", "example3@hotmail.com", "g2g@hotmail.com", "192@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
```

Basically, I want to concatenate onto this field with several ongoing email addresses as they add new users.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema for memberEmail so that it accepts an array. ie. `[String]`:

```js
teamMemberDetails: {
            memberName: String, default: "",
            memberEmail: [String], default: [],
            memberRole: String, default: ""
        },
```

and to update the document:

```
const teamMemberDetailsObject = 
{
  "memberEmail": [
    "example2@hotmail.com", 
    "example3@hotmail.com",
    "g2g@hotmail.com", 
    "192@hotmail.com"
  ]
}
```

if you'd like to initialize the array of emails, you can do that like this:

```
const updatedUser = await CompanyProfile.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $set: {teamMemberDetails: teamMemberDetailsObject}
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

If you'd like to add new emails to the `memberEmail` array in the same document in the collection, you can use the following:

```js
const updatedUser = await CompanyProfile.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
  $addToSet: {
    "teamMemberDetails.memberEmail":"newemailexample@hotmail.com"
  }
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

Comment: this will not update other values in the document

Comment: that is correct. If you'd like to update other values, include them in the $set object. For example: ```$set: {teamMemberDetails: teamMemberDetailsObject, employees: 5}```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the information, however this will over-write every time it's run. E.g if I add in those teamMemberDetails, the next time the API is called, then add in 1 member, only 1 user is shown in the DB.

Comment: Thankyou Stephen Taylor, in regards to this how would I update "teamMemberDetails.memberEmail":"newemailexample@hotmail.com" with the req.body.email? Seeing as it's covered in a string? This is exactly what I want but I want to use the body :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) together, you can update other values on the document
as well as push new items to the memberEmail array.

By using `$push`, you can add new items to the array.

```
// model 
teamMemberDetails: {
    memberName: String, default: "",
    memberEmail: [String], default: [],
    memberRole: String, default: ""
},

// dummy payload
const memberEmail = [
    "example2@hotmail.com", 
    "example3@hotmail.com",
    "g2g@hotmail.com", 
    "192@hotmail.com"
]

// Update call
const updatedUser = await CompanyProfile.updateOne(
    {_id: req.params.id},
    {
        $set: req.body,
        $push: {
            teamMemberDetails.memberEmail: memberEmail
        }
    },
    { new: true }
);
```

[Here's](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/GJubZC8DAON) a working example.